# Facebook page plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to integrate the Facebook page plugin in a web page (a simple html page with nothing else on it).

I'm following all the steps correctly but at the end, I can't see any Facebook page plugin on my page, just a link to my Facebook page.

Here is Facebook directions :

> 1. Include the SDK JavaScript on your page once, ideally right after the opening body tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

> 2. Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/hyundaifrance" data-width="300" data-height="400" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="false" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/hyundaifrance"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/hyundaifrance">Hyundai France</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

It seems so simple ! Should I ask what I'm doing wrong or what is the problem exactly ? Here is my actual "full-version" code :

```
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<h1>I want my Plugin to appear below this title</h1>

<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/hyundaifrance" data-width="300" data-height="400" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="false" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false" data-show-posts="true">
<div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/hyundaifrance"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/hyundaifrance">Hyundai France</a></blockquote></div>
</div>

</body>
```

I've been trying to change the Facebook SDK link as well but it didn't worked :

From this : `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";`

To this : `js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";`

And also this :  `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1";`

I also tried his code :

```
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '113869198637480',// The page id I want to use
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.3'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

Instead of this one, given on the Facebook page plugin instruction :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Didn't work either.

Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: An app id and a page id are two completely different things – so trying to initialize the SDK with a page id, when the parameter name clearly suggests that an app id is expected, makes no sense at all. // Have you checked your browser’s error console?

Comment: Do you have an plugin / addon which blocks social media?

Comment: I didn't know that. It doesn't work the "regular Facebook way" (without specifying any ID) anyway. The consol says no script error but here what I can read when I inspect the html : 
<script id="facebook-jssdk" src="//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3">
undefined
</script>
 Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't have a add-on which block social media. I'm using Firefox, but the plugin doesn't work on Chrome either.

Comment: _“It doesn't work the "regular Facebook way" (without specifying any ID) anyway”_ – that is not the “regular Facebook way”. When you get the code from their generator, it should ask you which app id to use, and put it into the code automatically. // Anyway, unlikely we can help you solve this, unless you show us a live example.

Comment: Oh so maybe the problem is, it should ask me which app id I use, but it doesn't ? If you need a live example, you can try it yourself : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This actually works but I have no idea why.

This is still not what you get when you use their code generator. 
What I did :

Once my page plugin generated, I picked the code from the source (with the console) instead of copying the code from the generator :

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<h1>I want my Plugin below this title</h1>

<iframe width="800px"
        height="800px"
        frameborder="0"
        allowtransparency="true"
        scrolling="yes"
        style="border: medium none; visibility: visible; "
        sdk=joey&amp;
        show_facepile=false&amp;
        show_posts=true&amp;
        small_header=true&amp;">

</iframe>
```

If you still have an explanation or a comment about this solution, I would listen to you because I won't use this code for a personal use but for a professional use and I REALLY need to do things the right way.

Thanks a lot for your answers :)